# R chisq.test test on data frame

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am attempting to run a chi sqare analysis on the data frame (called "habitat.re") below however im having difficulty as I've gotten it to read the data but its giving the wrong results, when i prompt it with $expected it returns 18 different colums when there should be 3 (one for each site).

All the tourorials ive been able to find have the data as a table, however i've not been able to convert it correctly myself.

[image: data frame]
[image: results]

Answer (score 4):

The `chisq.test` function is intended to work with two variables, or columns in this case.  If you want to compare all three of your columns, then I suspect you would want to compare `1-2`, `2-3`, and `3-3`, e.g.

```
chisq.test(x=habitat.re$Gidgee, y=habitat.re$`Ian's Place`)
chisq.test(x=habitat.re$`Ian's Place`, y=habitat.re$`Saw Mulga`)
chisq.test(x=habitat.re$Gidgee, y=habitat.re$`Saw Mulga`)
```

Actually, just typing in the above should reveal much useful information directly to the R console, something like this:

```
data:  habitat.re$Gidgee and y=habitat.re$`Ian's Place`
X-squared = 5.5569, df = 1, p-value = 0.01841
```

A sufficiently low `p-value` might indicate that the two columns are in fact dependent.

Comment: It still does the same thing, its comparing the probability of a literal value (eg. Probability of both having a “14” rather than comparing each groups scores) 

This example [video](https://youtu.be/LnaeG0MzQVw) [data frame](https://imgur.com/a/ZaNsm) has eye colour (x) and hair colour (y), and they it returns results for the likelyhood of the catagories.

Comment: What is the type of the three columns?  Is is numeric or factor?

Comment: they are observation counts, ive just imported from a CSV as a data frame and done some reshaping

Comment: `class(habitat.re$Gidgee)` <-- what does this show you?

Comment: it says "numeric"

Comment: Then perhaps something like the Pearson or Spearman correlation coefficient would make more sense here?

Comment: `cor.test(habitat.re$Gidgee, habitat.re$``Ian's Place``, method = "pearson")`

Comment: Perhaps, but i was interested in identifying if there was independence between the locations depending on the species, as i understand the chi-square should resolve this. I had been given a similar example by my lecturer previously [example](https://imgur.com/a/yuJgh). where fictional animals were compared across three environments (trees). Though it seems to deal with the data table differently to a data frame.

Comment: No, I think the issue your data.  For starters, your dataset is extremely small, only a handful of points.

Comment: My data set does contain 49 different species, so there is a decent number of obervations, I will look into your suggestion however learning how to use a chi-square test is probably the more important thing for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pearson's Chi-Squared Test requires a data frame to be made into a matrix table containing only the variables you need as numerical values. N.B. my data frame is called "habitat.re"

```
habitat.df<-data.matrix(habitat.re, rownames.force = NA)# convert to matrix table
habitat.df<- habitat.df[,-c(1,2,3)] # delete first 3 columns
rownames(habitat.df) <- habitat.re$COMMON.NAME #pull names from original
chisq.test(habitat.df) #do chisquare test
chisq.test(habitat.df)$expected #return predicted values
```

The following are images of my data frames

```
habitat.re
```

[image: image1]

```
habitat.df
```

[image: image2]

Comment: You should include this data in your question.